# Electrical meter running through eves

Tags: electrical

I had an electrician in to rewire my house and upgrade my electrical box. The electrician mentioned we needed to love the box from the original position.

When the box was moved, they cut a hole in my eves to run the pipe up. As a result, whenever it rains water pours straight onto the electrical box. Originally the wires run under the eves not thorough.

I am getting the eves sealed and the water re routed, but the contractor mentioned it may not be safe to have it this way.

Can anyone let me know if this is up to code ?

I am in Toronto

Thank you 
[image][image]

Comment: Did the electrician you hired pull permit from city? If yes, there should have been an inspection.

Comment: The city inspected it, and I received an ESA.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call a roofer and have him fix this.  That thing isn't an *eave*, it's a *gutter*.  It's supposed to catch the water off your roof and redirect it to *downspouts*.

Now you will be forced to cap off the gutter here, creating 2 segments of gutter where 1 resided before.  The new section will need its own downspout.

This is so incompetent that the electrician certainly would have been expected to mention you now need to do this. Perhaps it slipped someone's mind.

Comment: Yes, I need to get it fixed. I had a contractor over to look at it because the water was cascading down in such high volume, its caused a leak into my basement. ( neighbor also mentioned its super loud when it rains). before I pay to cut and redirect the guttering, I wanted to check if this was normal or not.